# Hibernate Entity Inheritance between Tables and Views

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

I have 2 tables and a view. TableA has certain fields. TableAHistory has the same fields as TableA. ViewAll is a union of TableA and TableAHistory, but additionally has a field called "current_vers" which denotes the current version ('Y' for TableA rows and 'N' for TableAHistory rows).

It seems like I should be able to take my existing Hibernate Entity bean for TableA and extend it to create a view for ViewAll. When I do this, however, I get errors regarding some DTYPE column that I don't have.

How should I do this?

**EDIT**: I need to be able to query the view, but have my results be TableA beans.

Comment: Do TableA and TableAHistory live in the same or separate DB table?

Comment: They are separate tables. There are triggers that copy data from TableA to TableB when TableA is modified.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are trying to do is to create an audit trail. My answer is based on that assumption.

The best Hibernate approved solution is to use [Hibernate Envers](http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/index.html). This allows you fine grained control of which fields to audit and a strong versioning implementation that works across relationships and inheritance boundaries. Envers also has APIs that support accessing prior versions to see the changes, timestamp, version etc.

If you still have flexibility in adding this, I strongly suggest using Envers.